# Can I export a log4j.properties while exporting RCPas product?

Tags: java, logging, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have a RCP application, in which I am using log4j.properties. I have kept this file just under the root file.
Now while using it inside a java file I must use the following lines :

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jConfPath);
```

But, for that purpose, I need to know the path for the exported log4j.properties. But, as currently no .properties is getting exported with RCP product export, I need to place them manually, use that path as `log4jConfPath`.

So, how can I export the log4j.properties in the RCP product.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build your RCP using **features** you can add extra files to the install root using the 'root' directive in the `build.properties` file for the feature. Something like:

```
bin.includes = feature.xml
root=file:log4j.properties
```

Note: this only works in a feature project, it will not work in a plugin. There is more information in the Eclipse [help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_rootfiles.htm)

When you run the RCP you can find the install directory using:

```
Location loc = Platform.getInstallLocation();
```

Comment: My project is not feature based. In this case, is there any workaround which I can use?

Comment: No, this requires feature based. It is not difficult to convert to be feature based.

Comment: Sorry to bother again! But, is there handy tutorial available for this? Thanks in Advance

Comment: There is a short [vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseFeatureProject/article.html) covering the basics